# Network traffic forwarding over grpc port

Tags: grpc, grpc-java

I have a requirement where I need to forward all the request from different sources to another network by grpc.

Request Server<-> Grpc Client <-> Internet <-> Grpc Server <-> Resource Server.

Request server and grpc client on same network.
Resource server and grpc server are on same network .

How to do I forward request server request to port that is sending data to grpc server ?

MY grpc server and client are in java so using grpc-java interface.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want a grpc-java-based proxy. "Grpc Client" in your diagram could be any HTTP/2 proxy. But you could use grpc-java to implement it.

I made [an example generic proxy](https://github.com/ejona86/grpc-java/blob/29728aeb003ced3c190197c176563643be22bef1/examples/src/main/java/io/grpc/examples/grpcproxy/GrpcProxy.java) a while back. It does not need any information about the methods it is proxying. You basically just create a new outbound RPC for each inbound RPC and plug the inputs of one to the outputs of the other and vise versa.